# Different currencies in the snippet and in the markup schema.org

Tags: seo, rich-snippets

Does anyone know what could be the reason of such an issue?
https://validator.schema.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Ftile.expert%2Fru-dk%2Ftile%2Fmutina%2Fmews%2Fa%2Fbom61-mewschevronchalk
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the schema markup. Posts here should be self-contained so that users are not required to visit your site. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like Google is trying to decide the currency from the page's content. Sometimes, making the currency a lot clearer on the page can help Google get it right.

I'm actually seeing it in USD which implies the site is sometimes detecting Googlebot is in the US and automatically converting the currency.